# Вывод фото юзера вк в приложение на C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, вконтакте

Здравствуйте!

Вот этим кодом получаем данные:

```
function GetProfile(uid){
                VK.api('users.get',{uids: uid,fields: 'first_name, photo_big, last_name'},function(data){

                var Fname ="";
                var Lname ="";
                var Photo ="";

                if(data.response){
                    Fname = data.response[0]['first_name'];
                    Lname = data.response[0]['last_name'];
                    Photo = data.response[0]['photo_big'];
                    var Profile = [uid,Fname,Lname,Photo];
                    SendToPlayer("OnGetPlayer", "" + Profile);
                }
                });
            }
```

Вот сюда они типа передаются:

```
private string _formatNameCache;
    private string _formatPhotoCache;

    public string FormatName
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_formatNameCache))
            {
                _formatNameCache = FirstName + " " + LastName;
                if (_formatNameCache.Length > 20)
                {
                    _formatNameCache = _formatNameCache.Remove(17) + "...";
                }
            }

            return _formatNameCache;
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос: как мне фото вывести сюда:

```
public class GameState : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SocialManager SM { get { return SocialManager.Instance; } }

    void Update()
    {
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (!SM.IsLoaded)
        {
            GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 50, Screen.height / 2, 200, 20), "Загрузка...");
            return;
        }

        if (SM.SocialData.ContainsKey(SM.UserId))
        {
            var data = SM.SocialData[SM.UserId];

            GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 100, 10, Screen.width, 20), data.FormatName);
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 50, Screen.height / 2, 100, 20), "Пригласить"))
        {
            SocialManager.InviteFriends();
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 50, Screen.height / 2 + 30, 100, 20), "Поделиться"))
        {
            SocialManager.PostToWall("Shot");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerator LoadPhoto()
{
  var data = SM.SocialData[SM.UserId];
  WWW www = new WWW(data.Photo);
  yield return www;
  GameObject.Find ("RawImage").GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = www.texture;
  StopCoroutine("LoadPhoto");
}
```